# How to ignore the previous way points of track in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a racing game in which I am using the same scene to divide it into different levels. So I want that my AI controlled car ignore the previous level's way points.

How I can do this?

Some part of my code is given below:

```
// Checks for the distance to next way point. If it is less than written value, then pass to next way point.
if (nextWaypointPosition.magnitude < nextWaypointPassRadius)
{
    currentWaypoint ++;
    totalWaypointPassed ++;

    // If all way points are passed, sets the current way point to first way point and increase lap.
    if (currentWaypoint >= waypointsContainer.waypoints.Count)
    {
        currentWaypoint = 0;
        lap ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either mark a variable with

> DontDestroyOnLoad

, which means that loading new scene the variables value will persist, for this case that is what you need.

If you have any other variables that need saving, and to make them persist even after the game was closed and reopened (like previous score, etc...) you can also use

> PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("FloatName", floatvalue);

and than you can access it by (essentia;;y just a key (string)-value(any standard type like int, float, double, etc..) pair

> PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("FloatName")

Answer (score 0):

You can create different waypointContainers for different levels
(like waypointContainer1,waypointContainer2 etc).
Then in your AI car's script in Start() function, you can assign current level's waypointContainer to AI car's waypointContainer. Something like this:

```
void Start(){
   if(levelNo == 1)   waypointContainer = waypointContainer1;
   else if(levelNo == 2)   waypointContainer = waypointContainer2;
   //And so on
}
```